# Viewpart Eclipse RCP resize

Tags: java, size, eclipse-rcp

I'm writing an Eclipse RCP 3 application. The application contains a menu on the left and the working view on the right. When the application starts the two viewparts are splitting the screen in two parts. Now I'm searching for a way to set the width of the menu so that it not use the full half part of the screen.

I have already done some tests with ISizeProvider but without any luck. What is the easiest way to set a default width on a viewpart?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a GridData for the controls inside the view part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started all over again with the mailexample in Eclipse. Now I hava it and without any need to code something.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything in the Eclipse source that actually uses the `ISizeProvider` so it looks like it may have been dropped for Eclipse 4.

If you want to set the relative sizes of views you put then in a Perspective and use the perspective layout factory to set the proportions of the window use by each view.